# Hyperv minikube malfunctioning (cannot start, delete or do anything connected with any functionalities)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have encounter problem with minikube on Windows with hyper-V After starting it successfully for first time i closed it, it crashed while closing, and i cannot access it via any means.

I have tried creating Primary Virtual Switch. I reinstalled by chocolatey both kubernetes and cube, re-enabling hyperV and deleting cube once again. The error i am getting: E0612 16:35:04.266260 7972 start.go:529] StartHost: start: exit status 1
For now minikube config logs look like that:
" minikube config view
- hyperv-virtual-switch: ExternalSwitch
- vm-driver: hyperv"

Most likely since virtual machine cannot be deleted nor started due to already existing and not existing it is some kind of log error i don't know how to repair.
Get-VM output doesn't show it exists. 
I highly hope i haven't missed solution for this one.

Comment: Are you running the `get-vm` as administrator?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes i have tried it, eventually got back to virtualbox and everything worked perfectly